# How to set the replyTo with JmsTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have a consumer consumes a message do some transformation and create a new Pojo and pass to a producer.
The producer sends the message in queue using the JmsTemplate.
The producer should set the headers of the original message like (JMSType, JMSCorrelationID, JMSExpiration, JMSDeliveryMode) to the new message to send.
But the producer should to change the replyTo Destination of the original message.
I haven't found a way to create a Destination and set to the JMSReplyTo.
Some have an idea how I can do that?

Maybe the JmsTemplate is not the correct class to do that.

```
public class Producer {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${jms-destination}")
    private String destination;

    public Producer(@Autowired JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void send(final MessageHeaders headers, final Pojo pojo) {
        Validate.notNull(order);

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, pojo, (message) -> {
          final Destination replyToDestination = ???;
          message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToDestination);

          message.setJMSType((String) headers.get(JmsHeaders.TYPE));
          message.setJMSCorrelationID((String) headers.get(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID));
          message.setJMSExpiration((long) headers.get(JmsHeaders.EXPIRATION));
          message.setJMSDeliveryMode((int) headers.get(JmsHeaders.DELIVERY_MODE));
          return message;
      });

    }
}
```

I have found only this way to do, but I don't like and I don't sure that this introduce side effect:

```
public class Producer {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${jms-destination}")
    private String destination;

    @Value("${jms-replyTo}")
    private String replyTo;

    public Producer(@Autowired JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void send(final MessageHeaders headers, Pojo pojo) {
        Validate.notNull(order);

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, order, (message) -> {
          final Destination replyToDestination = buildReplyTo();
          message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToDestination);

          message.setJMSType((String) headers.get(JmsHeaders.TYPE));
          message.setJMSCorrelationID((String) headers.get(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID));
          message.setJMSExpiration((long) headers.get(JmsHeaders.EXPIRATION));
          message.setJMSDeliveryMode((int) headers.get(JmsHeaders.DELIVERY_MODE));
          return message;
      });

    }

    private Destination buildReplyTo() throws JMSException {
      final Session session = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection()
          .createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      final Destination queue =
          jmsTemplate.getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, replyTo, false);
      return queue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution ? Please post the answer .. thanks

Comment: The solution is in the first comment.

Comment: I dont see any comments other than mine ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution creates side-along connections, which  are not closed.
You should use existing session object and send your pojo manually through send API. Use getRequiredMessageConverter to convert your pojo.

```
public void send(final MessageHeaders headers, Pojo pojo) {
    Validate.notNull(order);

    final String responseQueue = "responseQ";
    jmsTemplate.send(destination,
            session -> {
                Message message = getRequiredMessageConverter().toMessage(message, session);
                message.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue(responseQueue)); //fill queue

                //any other setters             
                return message;
            });         
}

// based on Spring JmsTemplate library
private MessageConverter getRequiredMessageConverter() throws IllegalStateException {
    MessageConverter converter = jmsTemplate.getMessageConverter();
    if (converter == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No 'messageConverter' specified. Check configuration of JmsTemplate.");
    } else {
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ermintar, your solution works almost perfect for me, but in my case I have a generic converter for any message because all of them is binary, compressed and signed. So how do I use the same converter for the JmsListener?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
message.setJMSReplyTo((Destination) ActiveMQDestination.createDestination("ORDER_REPLY_2_QUEUE", ActiveMQDestination.TYPE.QUEUE);
```

Even though casting seems unnecessary, doesn't work without casting.